# Are any JDBC drivers installed as default with Windows?

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc, odbc

I'm writing a Java program that retrieves data from an MS Access database. My code is as follows:

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + databaseLocation + databaseName +";selectMethod=cursor; READONLY=true; TYPE=FASTLOAD";

con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

I am using a basic JDBC:ODBC bridge. It seems a Type 4 driver would be better. However I'm writing the program to be used on a different PC and I would rather they do not have to install any drivers for it to work. I don't remember installing anything on my PC.

Can anyone tell me will this work with any copy of Windows? That is are the JDBC drivers I'm using installed with Windows or Java or Access by default?

Comment: Just ship the JDBC driver with your program? "Installing" is actually a very big word in case of a JDBC driver. Just having the JAR file in the Java application's runtime classpath is already sufficient. This is at highest matter of editing of the startup (batch) command of your Java application.

Comment: Ok interesting. I'll give it some thought. Thanks.

Comment: There are definitely no free Type4 drivers for Access. There are however some commercial ones. I *think* the hxtt driver is more popular than others (but don't know for sure as I have never used it, I just see it being mentioned more frequently): http://www.hxtt.com/access.html

Answer (score 3):

No, there are no type IV JDBC drivers installed on Windows.

I'm not aware of a free type IV JDBC driver for Access.

The JDBC-ODBC bridge is available for 32-bit JVMs, but not for 64-bit.  (A DLL is required that isn't part of the 64-bit JDK.)

Comment: Thanks so much. My goodness, you wouldn't believe how hard that was to find out. I've been Googling for hours :/

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

**duffymo** is correct as far as I know when he / she says "there are no type IV JDBC drivers installed on Windows"

hxtt.com/access.html is not a JDBC type 4 driver it uses Samba and not a Native Protocol which is what is required for a JDBC type 4 driver.

What you need is a JDBC type 3 driver which uses its own Network protocol to communicate between the client which in your case would be the remote PC and a server component. Commercially available is the [Easysoft JDBC-ODBC Bridge](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/jdbc_odbc_bridge/index.html) offers such a solution. You install the software on the machine containing the MS Access database or a machine that can use a UNC path to the access database and then you distribute the EJOB.jar file to the machines that require access to that database along with your Java application. You can use Easysoft from both 32-bit and 64-bit Java applcations.

Comment: Hmm, on the hxtt page I linked it says "*HXTT Access contains the only **type 4** JDBC driver packages for Microsoft Access*"

Comment: HXTT is AFAIK incorrect in their statement about there JDBC is type 4. They are providing a JDBC type 2 driver where the database is linked to via a Samba share. 

This is not JDBC type 4 as it has no native protocol built into the JDBC Driver. A good example of a JDBC type 4 driver would be the Microsoft JDBC driver for SQL Server. This uses TDS to communicate with SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware what Type 4 means. As I have never used hxtt I will need to rely on your experience that hxtt is not Type 4 ;)

Comment: It's a shame but they are not the only company out there to claim to have a type 4 JDBC driver.

Comment: Richard Spencer, do you have any affiliation with Easysoft?  I'd like to know if you're recommending from personal experience or a wish to sell a product.

Comment: duffymo - simple answer both. I work for Easysoft so selling a product is good but also I work directly with customers who use the product in commercial enviroments who like Russell have a real need for such a product. See my profile.

Answer (score 0):

> HXTT is AFAIK incorrect in their statement about there JDBC is type 4.

All drivers of HXTT drivers are type 4.

> it uses SMB and not a Native Protocol

Wrong. It can run for embeded mode, client/server mode, in-memory mode, mapped driver, SMB protocol, http protocol, https protocol,  and mobile OS.

If you choose to download and evaluate it, you will find the following information at http://www.hxtt.com/access.html ISN'T a lie:
HXTT Access contains the only type 4 JDBC(1.2, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.1) driver packages for Microsoft Access version from 95, 97, 2000, XP, 2002, 2003, 2007, to 2010, which supports transaction, embedded access, remote access, client/server mode, memory-only database, compressed database(.ZIP, .JAR, .GZ, .TAR, .BZ2, .TGZ, .TAR.GZ, .TAR.BZ2), SMB database(smb), url database(http, https, ftp), and java.io.InputStream database. Through the embedded Pure Java database engine, MS Access database can be deployed and acessed on any platform with JVM. With JDBC1.2, JDBC2.0, JDBC3.0, JDBC4.0, JDBC4.1, and SQL92 support, programmers needn't special coding, and DBA can use any Java database tool to access easily local data or remote data.

Answer (score 0):

Many powerful SQL syntax (for instance, select ... into outfile) at http://www.hxtt.com/access/sqlsyntax.html or SQL functions (for instance, GROUP_CONCAT) at http://www.hxtt.com/access/function.html are NOT supported by MS ACCESS engine at all. With HXTT Access' help, you can access local mdb/accdb file of UNIX/LINUX/MAC OS easily without any third-party component.